# Typesafe item removal from an array in an object - is it possible in a single function without assertion?

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I ask this mostly because I'm curious. The title is maybe a little complicated so... Let's say I have an object like this:

```
type ObjType = { items: Array<{ id: number }>; sth: number };
const obj: ObjType = {
  sth: 3,
  items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
};
```

Now I would want to remove an item from `obj.items` by id, let's say 2 and return the whole object with that item removed (new object, not mutated). This is generally straightforward in JavaScript, but I would want to do it with type safety preserved in TypeScript. I came up with something like this:

```
function removeItemFromArray<S, A extends { id: number }>(
  obj: S,
  field: keyof S,
  array: A[],
  valueToCompare: number
): S {
  return {
    ...obj,
    [field]: array.filter(i => i.id !== valueToCompare)
  };
}
```

but the `array` param seems redundant - it will always be `obj[field]`. But if I just used `obj[field]` there's no guarantee that it's an array. Now the question is how to make sure that `obj[field]` is an array of objects that contain id property? I'm pretty sure it's possible with conditional types but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional types won't help here, but you can get what you want by ensuring that `obj` has the right shape:

```
function removeItemFromArray<S extends { [f in F]: { id: number }[] }, F extends keyof S>(
  obj: S,
  field: F,
  valueToCompare: number
): S {
  return {
    ...obj,
    [field]: obj[field].filter(i => i.id !== valueToCompare)
  };
}

const obj = {
  sth: 3,
  items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
};

removeItemFromArray(obj, "items", 2);
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! I actually managed to come close to the answer (the `S extends...` part was pretty much identical), but I was using `keyof S` as a type `field` and it wasn't working, because it expected `obj` to contain only arrays of objects. I'm not quite sure why `extends` does the job here. Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: Without `extends` (`[f in keyof S]`), you're telling the type system that *all* fields in `S` must be of type `{id:number}[]`. With `extends`, you're telling the system that *some* are of this type. (That's a bit simplifying things of course, but I find that easier to understand than type theories).